# How to get the y/n key press directly without using choice and set /p

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, keypress

I am trying to get y/n keypress without using `choice` and `set /p`. I have used `del` like this:

```
@echo off
copy /y nul $~temp.txt
del /p $~temp.txt >nul
if exist $~temp.txt (
  echo/
  echo You pressed y.
) else (
  echo/
  echo You pressed n.
)
pause >nul
```

It does not directly takes key press. We have to press enter key after that. Any method without pressing the enter key is appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is, Wasif Hasan. I cannot provide further information at this time because, **1.** This isn't a give me the code or provide links to it, type of site, and **2.**  I have no real idea, from that code, what you're trying to do.

Comment: `del /Q` does not prompt for a key press, probably you mean `/P`?

Comment: It will be del /p, I mistakenly typed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (mis-)use [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), which prompts whether to continue copying when the `/W` option is specified; the `/L` switch prevents anything to be actually copied:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Capture first line of output of `xcopy /W`, which contains the pressed key:
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
    xcopy /W /L "%~f0" "%TEMP%"
') do set "KEY=%%K" & goto :NEXT
:NEXT
rem // Extract last character from captured line, which is the pressed key:
set "KEY=%KEY:~-1%"
rem // Return pressed key:
echo You pressed "%KEY%".

rem // Check pressed key (example):
if /I not "%KEY%"=="Y" if /I not "%KEY%"=="N" >&2 echo You pressed an unexpected key!
```

---

Alternatively, you could (mis-)use [`replace`](https://ss64.com/nt/replace.html), which prompts whether to continue replacing when the `/W` option is specified; the `/U` switch prevents anything to be actually copied when source and destination are the same:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Capture second line of output of `replace /W`, which is the pressed key:
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%K in ('
    replace /W /U "%~f0" "."
') do set "KEY=%%K" & goto :NEXT
:NEXT
rem // Return pressed key:
echo You pressed "%KEY%".

rem // Check pressed key (example):
if /I not "%KEY%"=="Y" if /I not "%KEY%"=="N" >&2 echo You pressed an unexpected key!
```

I have to admit that I cannot remember whether or not `replace` was available on Windows XP though.

Comment: I prefer the `replace.exe` method, and I can confirm that it exists in all versions of XP, including Home Edition and x64, and even Windows 2000.

Comment: Wasif Hasan, I would assume however that the `Y` or `N` would be language dependent, so if exact characters were required, these solutions wouldn't be suitable. If a positive or negative response was required, then obviously the last line would need adjusting accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @aschipfl. Your first method worked fine. So I accepted and upvoted your answer. But the second method is not understandable to me.

Comment: Thank you! The two methods are very similar, only `replace` returns the presses key in the second line, so `skip=1` is needed; I instructed the `replace` command to replace the batch script by itself, but with the `/U` option nothing is actually done, because this would replace a file only by a newer one; does this help you to understand it?

Comment: Ok, now I understand it, aschipfl

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I have found this way using `sc`:

```
@echo off
sc /? >temp.txt
for %%a in (temp.txt) do (
  if %%~za equ 4822 ( 
    echo You pressed y.
  ) else (
    echo You pressed n.
  )
)
pause >nul
```

This worked for me because the `sc` help screen has a direct y/n key press prompt in it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the output from `%__AppDir__%SC.exe /?` is locale dependent, so if that could be an issue for you, I wouldn't be relying on it having a specific size in bytes. I suppose that it will also, depending upon the locale, not only accept `Y` or `N` either. What is the reason for not using `Choice`? _The only thing I can think of at present is to be able to support [tag:Windows-XP]_.

Comment: I was doing this for some experiments so I didn't use choice, Compo

Comment: And also, I was doing this for some of my batch files that may run on windows xp.

Comment: Well, as I said, they would probably only work on the handful of `XP` machines, using your locale.

Comment: On Windows 10 `sc /?` does no longer prompt for a key press (at least on my machine)...

Comment: But my OS is Windows 7, @aschipfl.

Comment: Wasif Hasan, what is that supposed to mean? Are you telling us that your batch files are being written to support an Operating System only used by a very small number of people, _and most of those are using unofficial service packs and updates_. It seems as if you've not realised that three OS versions have been released in the last 7 years which supersede Windows 7. Do those not matter?

Comment: Yes compo they matter. I was not aware of the changes.